# Need help in understanding httperf num_calls and num_conns

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, httperf

When I run httperf with following options, the output is easy to understand.

Options: Make total 10 connections (num-conns) at rate of 10 (rate) connections/second with 2 request calls per connection (num-calls).
Output: 10 connections with 20 request calls

```
httperf -v --server www.example.com --wlog=n,$HOME/tmp/reqs.txt_httperf --rate=10 --num-conns=10 --num-calls=2 --hog 
Total: connections 10 requests 20 replies 10 test-duration 1.575 s
```

However, when I use following options, httperf output, output is confusing.
Options: Make total 4 connections (num-conns) at rate of 10 (rate) connections/second with 6 request calls per connection (num-calls).

```
httperf -v --server www.example.com --wlog=n,$HOME/tmp/reqs.txt_httperf --rate=10 --num-conns=4 --num-calls=6 --hog 
Total: connections 4 requests 8 replies 4 test-duration 0.455 s
```

It seems like when num-calls is greater than num-conns, number of requests made are 2*num-conns.

I am not following why num-calls be greater than num-conns. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why num-calls is greater than num-conns: on each connection, you can make multiple HTTP transactions (a.k.a "calls"). If num-conns = 4, on each connection, you make 2 transactions, then num-calls would be 8. 
Hope this helps.